# Auto adjust html table coulmns according to its content

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to 
1. adjust first column width according to largest length(it will be varying) of **td** element consisting it.
2. Want to set fixed width for other columns so that its content will be fit into one row (i.e. no wrapping).

Any help will be appreciated.

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">

table {
table-layout: auto;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}
table td {
border: 2px solid green;
}

    .style2
    {
        height: 23px;
        <!--width: 100%;-->
    <!--     width: 500px;-->
    }
    .style3
    {
        height: 23px;
        width: 30px;
  <!--       width: 92px;-->
        font-size: xx-small;
    }
    .style4
    {
        height: 23px;
   <!--      width: 109px;-->
        font-size: xx-small;
        background-color: #CCCCCC;
    }
         .style5
        {
            width: 30%;
            height: 30px;
         }
         .style6
         {
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
            padding: 1px 4px;
          }
         .style7
         {
            background-color: #CCCCCC;
         }
         .style8
         {
            height: 23px;
    <!--         width: 109px;-->
            background-color: #999999;
        }
        .style9
        {
            background-color: #999999;
        }
        .style10
        {
            height: 23px;
     <!--        width: 92px; -->
            background-color: #999999;
        }
        .style13
        {
            height: 23px;
     <!--        width: 92px;-->
            font-size: xx-small;
            background-color: #FFCCFF;
        }
        .style14
        {
            font-size: xx-small;
            background-color: #CCFF66;
        }
        .style18
        {
            font-size: xx-small;
            background-color: #CCCCCC;
        }
        .style19
        {
            height: 23px;
            width: 100%;
      <!--      width: 289px;-->
            font-size: small;
        }.

}

    </style>
</head>
<table style="height: 75px;" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 23px;">
<td style="height: 23px;" colspan="10">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; AW Build</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 23px;">
<th class="style2">&nbsp;Teams</th>
<td style="height: 23px;" colspan="3" class="style7">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 0512</td>
<td style="height: 23px;" colspan="3" class="style7">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 0511</td>
<td style="height: 23px;" colspan="3" class="style7">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 0512</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 23px;">
<td class="style19"><a href="http://localHost/SubLocation/index.html">AW-Consumer Packaged Good</a></td>
<td style="height: 23px;" class="style9">&nbsp;TC1121</td>
<td class="style10">TC1122</td>
<td style="height: 23px;" class="style9">TC113</td>
<td style="height: 23px;" class="style9">&nbsp;TC1121</td>
<td style="height: 23px;" class="style9">&nbsp;TC1122</td>
<td style="height: 23px;" class="style9">TC113</td>
<td style="height: 23px;" class="style9">TC1121</td>
<td style="height: 23px;" class="style9">TC1122</td>
<td class="style8">TC113</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 23px;">
<td class="style19"><a href="http://localhost/SubLocation/index.html">AW-User Management</a></td>
<td style="height: 23px;" class="style12">P-85 NAF-12 FF-3</td>
<td class="style13">P-85 NAF-12 FF-3</td>
<td style="height: 23px;" class="style12">P-85 NAF-12 FF-3</td>
<td style="height: 23px;" class="style18">P-85 NAF-12 FF-3</td>
<td style="height: 23px;" class="style18">P-85 NAF-12 FF-3</td>
<td style="height: 23px;" class="style18">P-85 NAF-12 FF-3</td>
<td style="height: 23px;" class="style18">P-85 NAF-12 FF-3</td>
<td style="height: 23px;" class="style18">P-85 NAF-12 FF-3</td>
<td class="style4">P-85 NAF-12 FF-3</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 23px;">
<td class="style19"><a href="http://localhost/SubLocation/index.html">Active Content Experience</a></td>
<td style="height: 23px;" class="style14">P-93 NAF-0 FF-7</td>
<td class="style15">P-93 NAF-0 FF-7</td>
<td style="height: 23px;" class="style14">P-93 NAF-0 FF-7</td>
<td style="height: 23px;" class="style18">P-93 NAF-0 FF-7</td>
<td style="height: 23px;" class="style18">P-93 NAF-0 FF-7</td>
<td style="height: 23px;" class="style18">P-85 NAF-0 FF-7</td>
<td style="height: 23px;" class="style18">P-85 NAF-0 FF-7</td>
<td style="height: 23px;" class="style18">P-85 NAF-0 FF-7</td>
<td class="style4">P-85 NAF-0 FF-7</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 23px;">
<td class="style19"><a href="http://localhost/SubLocation/index.html">Audit Subscription and License</a></td>
<td style="height: 23px;" class="style14">P-93 NAF-0 FF-7</td>
<td class="style15">P-93 NAF-0 FF-7</td>
<td style="height: 23px;" class="style14">P-93 NAF-0 FF-7</td>
<td style="height: 23px;" class="style18">P-93 NAF-0 FF-7</td>
<td style="height: 23px;" class="style18">P-93 NAF-0 FF-7</td>
<td style="height: 23px;" class="style18">P-85 NAF-0 FF-7</td>
<td style="height: 23px;" class="style18">P-85 NAF-0 FF-7</td>
<td style="height: 23px;" class="style18">P-85 NAF-0 FF-7</td>
<td class="style4">P-85 NAF-0 FF-7</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p>
    <br />
</p>
```

Comment: The first thing to do is change the comments into proper CSS comments, with `/*` ... `*/`. Using HTML comments is an error and will result in unexpected outcomes.

Comment: Ok. I will do that.

Comment: That said, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. It sounds like you're just trying to make every column use its natural width, so why use `width` properties at all? I mean, if you remove all widths, is there still a problem?

Comment: Yes, you are right! Just removed every width tag from page and now all columns are in their natural width. Thank you so much!